# Using Magsafe 1 85w 18.5v adapter for MacBook Pro 2015 15''

Tags: magsafe, charger

I want to use a Magsafe 1 85w 18.5v adapter for MacBook Pro 2015 15", which normally requires a Magsafe 2 85w 20v adapter.

Is the voltage difference is going to be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple says:](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD504LL/A/magsafe-to-magsafe-2-converter)

> The MagSafe to MagSafe 2 Converter allows you to use the MagSafe connector on your LED Cinema Display, Thunderbolt Display, or MagSafe Power Adapter to charge your MagSafe 2-equipped Mac computer.